# IntelliJ IDEA IDE gets lost of monitor's area when using more than one monitor on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I have an annoying situation when I use my preferred IDE, IntelliJ IDEA Community or Ultimate versions, with two monitors in my job and at home. Simply when I turn on my computer after using in the office where the monitor is located on top of my laptop, in my house, where the monitor is located in the left side of my laptop, the IDEA IDE that is continuing running from where I stopped in my office is still in the Windows toolbar.
However when I click on the IDEA's icon in the toolbar it never turns to active and present in the laptop's or in my left side's monitor. What is that unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after investigating a bit and doing some experiments I found the solution, you need to right-click the desktop area where this menu will pop-up:

[image]

Go and select "Display settings" and you will see that window:

[image]

What you see in this "Display Settings" Window is that your monitor's setup now (in your house) is the main laptop monitor in right and your laptop on left. But in your office your monitor was in the top of the screen, isn't it? 
**Solution:**
So what you need to do is to trick Windows and say that your actual monitor is in the top to be able to see the IDEA IDE. 
Steps:

1. Move the monitor number 2, dragging it with the mouse to the top of monitor number 1;
2. Press the "Apply" button;
3. You will see IDEA IDE, then drag it to the monitor 1;
4. Open the "Display Settings" again (right click the desktop and select "Display Settings");
5. Restore the configuration wished to your monitor, in other words: drag the monitor number 2 to the left side (if your physical monitor is really there).

**Warning**, that is not all, if in step 3 your cannot find the IDEA you need to change the position of the monitor 2 until you find the IDE.

The explanation for that issue is that Windows' monitor's logical area is not synchronizing with IDEA's positioning system. The IDEA's system does keep the last position where the IDE is, and the Operating System changes are not in synch with that. That potentially can happen also on linux or Macs computers.